# Group Table View - loading data

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios

Looking for help on how to properly load the data for a Grouped Table View.  I am using following code to load the data which I think should prepare an array "details" for "cellForRowAtIndexPath". However when I run the program I get the same data for all groups and it happens to be the last row in my data (which is in an NSArray called "Users").  Obviously I am doing something wrong but not sure what... please help.

```
// Customize the number of rows in the table view.
```

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

```
NSRange aRange;
aRange.length = 9; aRange.location = 16;
NSString *users = [self.Users objectAtIndex: section];
NSString *subtitle = [NSString stringWithString:[users substringWithRange:aRange]];
details = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:subtitle, subtitle, subtitle, nil] retain];

return [details count];
```

}

The data loading routine is as follows:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

// Configure the cell.
UIImage *cellImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"world.png"];
cell.imageView.image = cellImage;
cell.textLabel.text = [details objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
return cell;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

From what you've posted, `details` array is being reset every time the table views asks its data sources for the number of rows in a section. `details` is last set when `-tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` is last called i.e. for the last section. Once set, the same array provides the data for `cell.textLabel.text` for all the sections. So you are getting incorrect data.

It would be appropriate to calculate and store all the `details` arrays in a different array, say `detailsArray`.
The data can then be accessed them like
    `[[detailsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]`

Another problem with your code is that every time `numberOfRowsInSection` is called, data is being leaked as `details` is being reset without the earlier object being released.